# Textbox fill empty value every time while changing the db dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, database

I have one dropdown box and one textbox. I want when I select the dropdown value then, it will fill the matching database textbox value automatically based on the database drop-down selection.

Here is my code:-

**Dropdown and Textbox:-**

```
<select name="product" required>
 <option value=""></option>
 <?php                          
  while($productRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productResult)){?>
  <option value="<?php echo $productRow['ID'];?>">
  <?php echo $productRow['Category']; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>

<input placeholder="Phone Number" name="phoneNumber" id="pnum"  type="text">
```

**Script :-**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('select[name="product"]').change(function()
        {
     $('#pnum').val($('select[name="product"] option:selected').data('Mobile'));
        }

     );
     });

     </script>
```

Now textbox fills the empty value in every time when dropdown value change.
pls help a lot.

Comment: Sounds like a whole lot of pain. Simply make you <select> control to accept multiple selections i.e. <select name="product[]" multiple required>. The information sent on submit will be an array of selected products. Much easier than splitting and processing text items.

Comment: @jeff thanks your suggestion i added "multiple" on the dropdown. now also value cannot be passed

Comment: Did you put the [] in name='product[]'?

Comment: @jeff now I put <select name="product[]" multiple required> but not working

Comment: `.data('Mobile')` - what exactly are you trying to access here? I don’t see you setting such data anywhere before that, so what exactly do you think you would be reading back here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the html to

```
<select name="product[]" size=20 multiple required>
 <?php                          
  while($productRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productResult)){?>
  <option value="<?php echo $productRow['ID'];?>">
  <?php echo $productRow['Category']; ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Then remove the script because it is no longer required. All the selection of items is done in the `<select>` element.

On the server-side you will pickup the values in the product array.